# To users with more than 20,000 reputation points

Tags: discussion

I would like to suggest you visit "[Delete Votes of the Moderator Tool](https://english.stackexchange.com/tools?tab=delete&daterange=today)" when you have time. There are answers that need deleting. I am not saying you have to vote to delete all of them, but there are answers that are blatantly off-topic or don't answer the question at all. Since it takes only **three "delete votes"** from users with more than 20,000 reputation points to delete an answer, it would be far more effective than gathering **six "recommend to delete votes"** from users with less than 20,000 reputation points.

You have 15 delete votes you can cast a day if you have 20,000 reputation points. An additional vote is granted per 1,000 reputation, to a maximum of 30 delete votes. Please spend a few minutes a day and vote your conscience. That will greatly help the community maintain its quality and integrity.

Also, please review more "[Low Quality Posts](https://english.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts)", "[Late Answers](https://english.stackexchange.com/review/late-answers)" and "[First Posts](https://english.stackexchange.com/review/first-posts)". There are many questions and answers that need your attention.

When you have a few minutes, you can visit "[Close Votes of the Moderator Tool](https://english.stackexchange.com/tools?tab=close&daterange=today)" and review "most votes". There are questions that you might have missed while reviewing "close votes".

There are only a limited number of users who are regularly reviewing those posts and I think the more often you review them, the less chance of leaving low-quality answers on ELU.

What are your thoughts?

Comment: IMO, 1 "delete" = 2 "recommend deletions". So if there already are 2 "delete" votes, adding 2 "recommend deletions" should clear it from queue.

Comment: Re your last paragraph -- about number of votes:  consider making that a separate question.

Comment: @ab2 Do you think it will be a legitimate question as a separate one? Some might find it too trivial or meaningless to raise the issue if they don't care.

Comment: @Rathony As the delete-vote mechanism is a site-wide thing, it should be raised on Meta.SE. It's possible there are already relevant questions there. (The question on getting ELU users to use delete votes is rightly asked here)

Comment: Like @ab2 said, about number of votes, make it a separate question. But you may post it on meta ELU itself, because, _["Users Can Report Bugs On Whatever Child Meta Site Suits Them"](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/250152/5832912)_ says Tim Post, Director of Stack Overflow Communities

Comment: It is legitimate as a separate question because it may have a simple answer in contrast to philosophical and behavioral questions.

Comment: @ab2 I removed the part and let me think about it for a while. At this moment, I don't think the question is worth it.

Comment: [**How can we get more 10k and 20k users to help clean up the site?**](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/q/6684/50044)

Answer (score 6):

## I agree.

We need more participation from 10k and 20k users

Visit just any “top reviewers all time” list, and you’ll see how much time and effort our gems have invested in ELU to give you and me an ELU clutter-free.

I wish to see all of you use, nay, utilise to the fullest, all of your privileges. Then we can all gift to our future visitors, an ELU that’s beautiful, an ELU that means business.

A VLQ post often goes straight to the bank laughing, meanwhile, all those inspired follow suit, and ruins our ELU and that’s on me and you.

It takes ages to reach 6 "recommendations" to delete certain pages. So with the rare “delete” privileges…

## What are you waiting for! Let’s burn those that deserve it!

<sub>**P.S.** I appreciate all the great posts you have made over these years. If you are unable or uninterested in donating a few extra minutes from your ELU time for reviews, that’s perfectly okay. Please continue posting nice stuff, that’s what we need more.</sub>

[image: I want you!]

Comment: I can't bring myself to upvote this, it sounds too much like an electoral campaign :) But thank you for making me smile. :)

Comment: @Mari-LouA Hehe. How about now? Too much? :)